# Can anyone help me understand the quotient of two vector spaces specified in the question?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let v be the set of all polynomials, p be a fixed polynomial of degree n and W be the polynomials divisible by p. Why is V/W an n-dimensional vector space?

Comment: The quotient $V/W$ is a vector space if and only if $W$ is a subspace of $V$. It is easy to check that is the case here.

Comment: How to show v/W is of dimension n?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$V/W$ is the remainders after division by p.

These are all polynomials of degree less than or equal to n-1.

The set of polynomials of degree n-1 is an n-dimensional space.

It is closed under addition, and scalar multiplication, etc.  Show that the other axioms that define a vector space still hold.

Comment: I am quite new to the material. I mean I can guess that is the case intuitively. Can you explain why is V/W the remainder after division by p?

Comment: $V/W$ says that $x,y \in V$ are equivalent if there is a vector $w \in W$ such that $x =y - w.$  i.e. if $\gcd (x,p) = \gcd (y,p) \implies x\equiv y.$  If $x$ is of degree greater than $n-1$, then there is some multiple of $p$ we can subtract from $x$ and find an equivalent $y$ of degree $\le n-1$

Comment: So x and y in your previous comment are two polynomials from V and p is a polynomial of degree n? What do you mean by gcd(x, p)?

Comment: You said p is a polynomial of degree n in your set-up!  gcd is the greatest common divisor, and that isn't what I meant to use there.... lets clean that up.  If $x = ap + r$ and $y = bp + r$ then  $x\equiv y.$

Answer (score 1):

I assume that $v$ is the set of all polynomials with coefficients in a field, let say that $v=k[X]$.

**Hint.** Use euclidean division by $p$ in $k[X]$ to prove that $(1\mod p,X\mod p,\cdots,X^{n-1}\mod p)$ is a basis of $v/W$. Basically, for each $f\in k[X]$ there exists $(q,r)\in k[X]$ such that: $$f=pq+r\textrm{ with }\deg(r)\leqslant n.$$
Take $\mod p$ this last equation.

Comment: What is k[X] in your answer?

Comment: $k[X]$ is the set of polynomials with coefficient in $k$, this is really the $v$ you defined.

Comment: What does X^n mod p mean?

Comment: $X$ is the variable of your polynomials and $\mod p$ means that you see $X$ as an element of $v/W$. Basically, $X^i\mod p$ is the remainder in the euclidean division of $X^i$ by $p$.